# Wifi speed is 11Mbps but my download speed is 600-700Kbps

Tags: wireless-networking, download, connection, internet-speed

I am subscribed a 11Mbps wifi in Jakarta, Indonesia. However my download speed is about 4.94Mbps after testing it on Speedtest.

Here is the problem:

1. my download speed is about 600-700kbps in Internet Download Manager.
2. My download speed is about 2.0Mbps on steam

Comment: what speed do you have using cable? the first poing could be to determine if the problem is on wireless network or if is an ISP problem.

Comment: Remember that your download speed is always limited by the server you are downloading from. If they are not delivering faster, a fast line doesn't change that.

Comment: A network is only as fast as the slowest connection.

Answer (score 1):

1 Byte is made up of 8 bits. Network link speeds are measured in kilo | mega | gigabits ( 1,000 | 1,000,000 | 1,000,000,000 bits) per second, but file transfer speeds are often measured in Kibi | Mebi | GibiBytes (1,024 | 1,048,576 | 1,073,741,824 Bytes) per second.

600 KibiBytes/sec is about 4.8 megabits/sec, which is a decent speed for 11 megabit/sec 802.11b Wi-Fi and matches your Speedtest.net results. So I'll bet your Internet Download Manager is reporting in KibiBytes/sec.

Comment: Also, Steam reports in Megabytes per second. Not sure if the OP is converting, But since there are 8 bits in a byte, 2MB/s as steam would report it translates to about 16mbit. 11mbit would be about 1.4MB